# getting firefox chrome-window from XPCOM component

Tags: firefox, browser, mozilla, xpcom, browser-addons

I am writing an XPCOM object that will like to access the main firefox window, and the open tabBrowsers. What is the interface that I should use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#From_a_dialog).